# Force Mobile Devices to Open Number Keyboard in Custom Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, newform, data-form-web-part

I have created a custom form in SPD 2013 for a SharePoint Online list, using a DataFormWebPart.

When I go to edit a field on the form from a mobile device, I would like the browser to default to the number keyboard for certain fields. As I understand it, this is achieved in HTML using input type="number", but the DataForm web part automatically creates the input HTML behind the scenes, and I can tell from inspecting source that it sets the type as "text".

I welcome any suggestions on how best to make mobile devices default to the number keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this JSLink example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-94145281